# Laptop comes out of hibernation at random times

Tags: windows-7, laptop, hibernate

I have a Sony Vaio VPCEB24FX laptop that will wake up from hibernation at random times on its own. It will be hours after I put it in hibernation. It has Windows 7 64-bit. I tried the command prompt suggested in other answers but all I get is this message:

> Wake History Count - 1
>
> Wake History [0]
>
> Wake Source Count - 0

If I shut down the computer it stays off. As for waking up from "sleep", I don't know because I don't use it; just hibernate.

I noticed this starting right after the first time I used Windows Media Center. I have gone through the program and can't find anything that would wake up the computer from hibernation. It still happens when Media Center is shut down completely.

**Edit**: I tried the solution in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/466731/laptop-comes-out-of-hibernation-at-random-times/466744#466744) but there isn't an option like that to uncheck. All it has is the following:

[image]

Comment: @josh, next time you can also flag the answer as not an answer (clean up both parts)

Comment: @soandos OK.  I did flag it with a comment.  Would "not an answer" be better?

Comment: Yes, but what you did is fine.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I merged your two unregistered user accounts. Please consider properly registering with the site, so you can add comments to answers to your question.

Comment: Regarding your edit: We must have different versions. I've updated my answer with a method that relies on the Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if your network card is allowed to wake the device?
This is only used if you want to use wake-on-lan, but sometimes it picks up some odd packets and starts up the laptop or pc.

You can check this by following these steps:

- Go to Device Manager by going to START - RUN - devmgmt.msc
- Open the Network Adapters section and check each adapter for the following:

  - Open the properties of the device
  - Open the Power management tab
  - Allow this device to wake the computer must be TURNED OFF

You can also check that a mouse or trackball is the issue. Sometimes it's the keyboard. It is hard to tell.

You can always check why the pc came back alive by typing the command
powercfg -lastwake
or to see what is keeping your pc from sleeping:
powercfg -requests

In my case, my keyboard and mouse gave a wake pulse to my computer at random times. This is fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

Windows Media Center might be the culprit indeed, since it can wake the computer up to perform scheduled downloads.

How to disable:

1. Open Windows Media Center.
2. Enter **Settings → General → Automatic Download Options**.
3. Uncheck **Wake the computer to run this task**.
4. Click OK.

Another method from [SevenForums](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/121903-windows-media-center-updates-enable-disable-waking-computer.html):

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and run **taskschd.msc**.
2. In the console tree, enter **Task Scheduler Library → Microsoft → Windows → Media Center**.
3. Open **mcupdate**.
4. In the **Conditions** tab, uncheck **Wake the computer to run this task**.
5. Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of silly, but I had a problem like this; bear in mind I'm not familiar with your laptop; and if it doesn't help you, it may help people who google similar problems. Anyway, my laptop had a hinged lid but no clasp, it relied on a magnet or some such to determine if it was closed. Occasionally some external force would cause my laptop to open up just enough in my bag to wake up - If you can Imagine a running laptop in suffocating bag starting beeping very loudly about overheating pretty soon!

Due to this, I just stopped using hibernation when putting my laptop away.